# How can we add calculated custom fields on a process in Azure Devops Boards

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

How can we add calculated custom fields on a process in Azure DevOps Boards. Is there any extensions that can be used for creating a Calculated custom field?

Comment: What is a _Calculated Custom field_? Please elaborate on your requirement with an example to demonstrate your need, perhaps [custom rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops) are what you are looking for

Comment: Did you mean creating a custom field Calculated to your project process. Please check out below steps.

Answer (score 2):

Azure DevOps support rollups in the backlogs only: [Display rollup progress or totals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/display-rollup?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process).
To use your own logic, you can:

1. Create an extension (for example [WSJF (Weighted Shortest Job First)](https://github.com/microsoft/AzureDevOps-WSJF-Extension)).
2. Use [az boards work-item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/boards/work-item?view=azure-cli-latest) to get, calculate, and update fields.
3. Use Excel to create calculated columns and publish fields: [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process)

Comment: Is there any plugin available in the marketplace similar to WSJF plugin? we are planning to add more calculated fields that display values or perform a calculation based on the values of other fields.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an extension and upload it to the marketplace.  The extension will be a node application and in your case a custom control.  Once you've loaded the extension, you can share it with your organization and then add it to the form page for your process.  When the form is displayed, the extension will run and can read and write fields for your Work Item.

This document will get you started:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/custom-control

I found that rather than building the extension from scratch, it's easier to download the samples and hack away the extension samples you don't need.  Just delete the folders in src/samples you don't need, build it and upload into devops.  The browser console will be your friend for debugging your extension.

You can get the samples here:  https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample

Answer (score -2):

If you mean creating a custom field `Calculated` to your project process. You can follow below steps.

1, Go to organization settings -->Process-->Select the process which your project is currently using.

If your project is using the System processes: Agile, Basic, Scrum, and CMMI. You need to [create Inherited processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops#create-an-inherited-process). For System processes are locked from being changed. See [System versus inherited processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/inheritance-process-model?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process).

After you select your project process. You can select work item types to add the custom field. See [Add a custom field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-field?view=azure-devops#add-a-custom-field).

2, If your project was using System processes. After you created the Inherited process, and added the custom field. You need to change your project process to this newly created inherited process. See [Change the project process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/change-process-agile-to-scrum?view=azure-devops#change-the-project-process).

Comment: I think the OP means a custom field that is calculated. For example, Effort - Completed work = Remaining Effort

Comment: This does not explain how to add a calculated field, which isn't actually supported.